# Best solutions for multi-language website

Tags: html, multilingual

I'm currently having a regular HTML website in multiple languages. I've tried something with PHP, but that didn't turned out very well. What I need is a Multi language site without: 
- Subdomains (like `en.domain.tld`) 
- Paths (like `domain.tld/en`)

What I do need: 
- Languages that are stored in sessions/cookies
- Languages which can be used around the whole site (with one place to store the language files, if that's necessary)
- Preferably without visible indications in the URL (like `?lang=en`).

A bit like how Google does it, because I also have multiple TLDs, so the user shouldn't be required to change their language by visiting another domain like `.de`, if they set their language to English from the `.com` site.

What is the best solution for this? I'm also very new to making websites, so that's why I'm asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i prefer to do is

1. Create a localization directory at the top level of your app

index.html

app.js

localization/

2. Inside localization directory create two files

web-en.json

```
{
"title":"Hello world",
"desc":"languages are fun"
}
```

web-es.json

```
{
"title":"Hola Mundo",
"desc":"idiomas son divertidos"
}
```

3. Install this library  "jquery-localize": "https://github.com/coderifous/jquery-localize.git"

> bower install jquery-localize

4. Include the library
5. Add the attributes to your HTML tags

   Hello World will go here

   Translated desc will replace this text
6. Call the library onReady

`$(function(){ 
    $("[data-localize]").localize("localization/web");
};`

Comment: Nice! But how exactly do you call these languages?

Comment: in javascript, I am not sure what you mean

Comment: Using the browser I mean. With my old method, I had to put: `?lang=en` behind the URL.

Comment: oh that works if you want to do it that way and get the arguments from the window.location

Comment: Thanks! Also; a bit off-topic but every time I reload the page, the language is back to normal.. Do you maybe have an solution for that?

Comment: as in the lang?=es goes away? not so sure

Comment: you can persist this by using cookies, or just let the library handle the language detection as its part of the window.navigator.language standard js object

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible to translate a website and save its selected language across the whole website without changing the URL.

You can use Cloud Translation, it's a free and open-source project from Angry Monkey Cloud: https://github.com/angrymonkeycloud/CloudTranslation.

You should add a reference to jQuery first, then to the CloudTranslation JavaScript file:

```
<script crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://cdn.amcapi.com/translation/cloudtranslation-1.0.0.min.js"></script>
```

And add the configuration within the HTML head as follows:

```
<script type="application/json" id="CloudTranslationConfig">
    {
  "Settings": {
    "DefaultLanguage": "en",
    "UrlLanguageLocation": "", // Keep empty
    "TranslatorProvider": "Azure", // Could be empty if you want to provide the translations manually
    "TranslatorProviderKey": "{Your Microsoft Azure Translator Key}",
    "UrlLanguageLocation": "Subdirectory"
  },
  "Languages": [
    {
      "Code": "en",
      "DisplayName": "English"
    },
    {
      "Code": "de",
      "DisplayName": "Deutsch"
    }
  ]
}
</script>
```

and add your own custom select (dropdown) having the class "CloudTranslationSelect" to display the list of predefined languages.

More information found on https://www.angrymonkeycloud.com/translation